# Is there any open source docx render available?

Tags: ms-word, apache-poi, openxml, docx4j

I was wondering if there are any open source docx renderer available. Given a OOXML snippet, is there some way to create an image of it. Say I have the OOXML for a paragraph in Microsoft word document, can I get the rendered paragraph as an image?

Comment: I don't know the format but I believe a snippet would most likely not be enough to reconstruct the layout of the snippet. And there are almost certainly better methods than butcher a word document to extract a snippet.

Comment: I said snippet just as an example. I was just looking to render a word document without Microsoft Word. I have the whole document. Just want to create an image of it.

Comment: There are apparently many (paid) solutions for this problem. Take a look at them. But then we are getting into library discussions and stack overflow is not the place to do that.

Comment: Use Apache OpenOffice or LibreOffice ?